# The system defined Contributors group got deleted from AzureDevOps project. How to recreate it?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, user-permissions, usergroups

I deleted the Contributors group. Now only project administrator can edit the work items.

I tried adding an another group with name '*Contributors*' and added permissions, but it didn't work as same as the system defined ones.

How to recreate/recover the same Contributors group?

Comment: The group name should be [ProjectName]\Contributors, where [ProjectName] is the name of your Azure DevOps project. Have you tried that?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko - When I tried to add a new group with the mentioned group name, then an inline validation appeared for the group name as 'Group name must not include the following characters: , " / \ [ ] : | < > + = ; ? * @ ~ ' & $ #'